# Routing based on data in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using Asp.Net MVC 4, and am unsure of the best way to approach a routing problem. The site needs to support static urls which are mapped to controller/actions in the usual way:

/about
/contact
/etc

But it also needs to map to items from the database:

/clothes
/clothes/jumper
/clothes/outdoor/blue-coat

I've managed to get this working by adding a constraint in my default route listing all my static controllers:

```
constraints: new { controller = "About|Contact|Etc" }
```

Then adding a catch all route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Error",
    "{*url}",
    new {controller = "CatchAll", action = "Index"}
);
```

Then the CatchAllController handles the non-static urls, and 404s for non-existing data.

Is this the best way of doing this? Or is it better to write a custom route handler? Or is there something else? I'm aware that the constraint regular expression could get quite long, and it's also another thing to remember to add when adding a new page.

Comment: This general approach works for me in a current project.